# NUnit generated Mock Repository returns the same object in different test cases

Tags: c#, asp.net, nunit, moq, rhino-mocks

Hi I am just starting off with Test Driven Development. I have a code where I have two test cases

```
     [Test, Order(3)]
    public void Should_Not_Create_ServiceAccountTaxCode_If_BillType_Is_Not_RateReady()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        var customerDetailsViewForBillTYpeRateReady = new CustomerTaxDetailsView
        {
            BillType = (int)BillTypes.BillReady
        };

        _repository.Stub(x => x.GetCustomerDetailsForTaxes(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(dict.Dequeue());


        //ACT
        var result = _concern.PopulateServiceAccountWithTaxDetails(Arg<int>.Is.Anything);

    [Test, Order(4)]
    public void Should_Create_ServiceAccountTaxCode_If_BillType_Is_RateReady()
    {
        //ARRANGE
        const int serviceAccountId = 1;
        var customerDetailsView = new CustomerTaxDetailsView
        {
            BillType = (int)BillTypes.RateReady,
            ServiceTypeId = (int)ServiceTypes.Electric
        };
       _repository.Stub(x => x.GetCustomerDetailsForTaxes(serviceAccountId))
            .Return(customerDetailsView).Repeat.Once();
        var result = _concern.PopulateServiceAccountWithTaxDetails(serviceAccountId);
```

And I am generating the mock using following syntax in the

```
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
     _repository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IServiceAccountTaxCodeRepository>();
```

The only problem is that in the second test case also my result object is customerDetailsViewForBillTYpeRateReady from first test case. Why is this happenning. And if i run these tests independently then everything is passed. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: dict.dequeue actually dequeues customerDetailsViewForBillTYpeRateReady  object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your problem is because you configure method `GetCustomerDetailsForTaxes()` in two places on the same `_repository` object. This configuration will be executed always:

```
_repository.Stub(x => x.GetCustomerDetailsForTaxes(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(dict.Dequeue());
```

The reason is because you specified `Arg<int>.Is.Anything`. So, test cases will grab that configuration because in second test case you have `const int serviceAccountId = 1;` which is also `Arg<int>.Is.Anything`.

I will rather in first test case specify

```
 const int serviceAccountId = 2;
_repository.Stub(x => x.GetCustomerDetailsForTaxes(serviceAccountId)).Return(dict.Dequeue());
```

Now you will have different configuration for both test cases.